# Materialize.css column not scaling to full row height

Tags: css, reactjs, web, material-ui, materialize

I'm using React.js, Materialize.css and some MaterialUI components together for creating a website.

I've created a header (React component, basic div with title and logout button) for my site using a **Materialize.css "grid"**.

Problem: I use this react component in 2 different places. 
In place 1, the height of the column is the same as the row.
In place 2, the height of the column is half of the height of the row.

Here's the code:

**The react component that is a header**

```
export class Header extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)

}

render() {
    let logoutBtn = <div className="col s2 offset-s2">
        <FlatButton href="/logout/" backgroundColor="#ffffff" hoverColor="#d7d7d7" label="LOGOUT" />
    </div>

    if (this.props.hideLogoutButton) {
        logoutBtn = null
    }

    return (
        <nav className="top-nav">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col s5 offset-s2">
                        <a className="page-title">{this.props.title}</a>
                </div>
                {logoutBtn}
            </div>
        </nav>
    )
}
}
```

**Usage in place 1**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <Header title="Inspection" />
                <SideBar infolder={true}/>
            </header>
            <div className="content">
                <InspectionSearchView />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**Result in place 1**
[result1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IlG7z.png)

**Usage in place 2**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <header>
                <Header title="Portfolio" />
                <SideBar infolder={true}/>
            </header>
            <div className="content">
                <PortfolioSearchView />
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
```

**Result in place 2**
[result2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvdEt.png)

Answer (score 1):

Generally cols are not using the full height of the surrounding rows.
The nav should set a height of 64px and a line-height of 64px.

By default it works with your markup.

See https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PjKrgK

If not there may be side effects of other components or your CSS. Then try the following solution using flexbox to set the cols to the same height (equal height).

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/d63977599a4efd86820d84fd9c0bf7ca5479744e/dist/css/materialize.css#L3396

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/0e13b80f6bfee1700dd2c2aa49494a44c8a61acb/sass/components/_grid.scss#L68

Because this is not the case by default:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mwMZKr

You have to apply some equal-height solution, for example flexbox:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KqvjeR

```
.col {
  align-items: stretch;
  flex: 1
}
.row {
  background:green;
  display: flex;
}
```

But imho this looks like something different has side effects on your button. Try to inspect the button, col and row and see what affects them.

Without any CSS code and just screenshots and the normal HTML markup it is a bit hard to fin the exact cause for this behavior.